# Set up development environment for OSGeo4W/QGIS with C++

Tags: c++, qt, qgis

I want to set up a development environment to make C++ applications which use QGIS elements like 'map canvas' etc.

I could not find any working tutorial or documentation to solve it with Qt or Visual Studio C++.
Could You please give me some idea to solve it or show the main steps i need to follow?